# Title: TypeConversionException when Comparing Integer Values in Apache Camel

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a piece of Apache Camel code where I'm trying to compare an integer value with a constant using the `<simple>` expression.

However, I'm encountering a `TypeConversionException` with the error message saying

> Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the
> required type: java.lang.Integer with value 3 > 0 due to
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3 > 0".

Here's the code snippet:

```xml
<setProperty name="retryCount">
    <constant>0</constant>
</setProperty>
<loop>
    <simple>3 > ${exchangeProperty.retryCount}</simple>

    <!-- do something -->

</loop>
```

I've tried different variations of the expression, such as `<simple>${exchangeProperty.retryCount} &lt; 3</simple>`, but the exception persists. How can I resolve this issue and successfully compare the integer values? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should write `<loop doWhile="true">` to tell Camel to expect (in the simple expr) a boolean (and not an integer with the count).